# No autoware.ai folder, when launching autoware in Docker

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, guys,

when running autoware after first installation from docker, no autoware folder is found, do you have any clues?

proceeding every steps with the latest guides, until :'

cd autoware.ai '

Docker is successfully installed with Ubuntu 18.04 and launching with tag cuda off.

---

### update

only folder  'Autoware' and 'shared_dir'  exist

> autoware@w-VirtualBox:~$ ls
> Autoware shared_dir

---

### Terminal

> w@w-VirtualBox:~$ sudo docker run hello-world

> ...
> Hello from Docker!
> ...

> w@w-VirtualBox:~$ git clone
> > https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/docker.git
> > Cloning into 'docker'... remote:
> > Enumerating objects: 124, done.
> > remote: Counting objects: 100%
> > (124/124), done.
> > 
> > remote: Compressing objects: 100%
> > (81/81), done. remote: Total 625
> > (delta 66), reused 93 (delta 43),
> > pack-reused 501 Receiving objects:
> > 100% (625/625), 987.21 KiB | 4.33
> > MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100%
> > (280/280), done. w@w-VirtualBox:~$ cd
> docker/generic
>
> w@w-VirtualBox:~/docker/generic$ sudo
> > ./run.sh -s --cuda off
> > 
> > [sudo] password for w:  Using options:
> >   ROS distro: melodic     Image name:
> > autoware/autoware     Tag prefix: latest
> >   Cuda support: off   Pre-release
> > version: off  UID: <1000> Launching
> > autoware/autoware:latest-melodic To
> > run a command as administrator (user
> > "root"), use "sudo <command>". See
> > "man sudo_root" for details.
> > 
> > autoware@w-VirtualBox:~$ cd
> autoware.ai bash: cd: autoware.ai: No
> such file or directory

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354605/no-autoware.ai-folder,-when-launching-autoware-in-docker/) by [chris909](https://answers.ros.org/users/55692/chris909/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-06-11**:
What shows up if you `ls` in the Docker container?

Also, FYI - launching the container using `sudo` is not our typical setup. We assume that people have followed the [Post-Installation Steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) after install to allow them to run Docker commands as a non-root user.

**Comment by [chris909](https://answers.ros.org/users/55692/chris909/) on 2020-06-11**:
if **ls**, only "Autoware" and "shared_dir" exist,  but no autoware.ai,

autoware@w-VirtualBox:~$ ls
Autoware  shared_dir

thanks for the user group information, I add it, but still have no clue on the unfound directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of the tutorials are written assuming you're building from source. In the from-source build instructions, we have you create a folder called `autoware.ai` to use as your workspace. In the Docker, containers, however, the workspace folder has always been called `Autoware`. This is a discontinuity but it was a decision between changing an existing pattern to match a new one or keeping what is expected by existing users. We chose the latter. So, if you follow any tutorials using Docker, just replace `autoware.ai` in the path with `Autoware`

If you would like this changed, feel free to submit an issue at https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/docker/-/issues.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris909](https://answers.ros.org/users/55692/chris909/) on 2020-06-12**:
thank you, after cd to "Autoware", it can be launched right now.